# Shoelace formula in racket

Tags: list, recursion, position, racket

[image]

I am having problems in finding a way to recursively calculate the area.

```
(check-expect(signed-area(list (make-posn 1 2)(make-posn 3 4)(make-posn 5 6)(make-posn 1 6)))8)
```

(check-expect(signed-area(list (make-posn 1 2)(make-posn 11 3)(make-posn 12 9)(make-posn 2 10)))70)

```
    (define (signed-area lop)
  (cond
    [(< 3 (length lop)) 0]
    [else
     (abs (/ (+(-(* (posn-x (first  lop)) (posn-y (second lop))) 
                 (* (posn-x(second lop)) (posn-y(first lop))))
               (-(* (posn-x (second  lop)) (posn-y (third lop)))
                 (* (posn-x(third lop)) (posn-y(second lop))))
               (-(* (posn-x (third  lop)) (posn-y (fourth lop))) 
                 (* (posn-x(fourth lop)) (posn-y(third lop))))
               (-(* (posn-x (fourth  lop)) (posn-y (first lop))) 
                 (* (posn-x(first lop)) (posn-y(fourth lop)))))
               2))]))
```

I am out of ideas on how to recursively go through the list, and remove the first posn after it went through the list. Since the code I have is limited to 4 points and I have to make this to be at least 3 points

Comment: `(cddr lop)`, however `lop` = `list-of-pairs` is misleading, because I would imagine a list of pairs like an association list - very often called by lispers `alist` in the code - and which is `'((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5. 6))` a list-of-pairs ... but your list-of-pairs is a property list! `(x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 ... xn yn)` and this is called by lispers very often `plist`. So any lisper would immediately understand this structure if you call it `plist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution I - direct recursion**

However, the problem is the `absolute` function at the end over the entire formula.
For this to be executed at the very final on the entire sum, you have to put your function into the outer function and apply `abs` on the function-call:

```
(define (signed-area plist)
  (define (.signed-area plist)
    (cond ((< (length plist) 3) 0)
          (else (+
                 (/ (- (* (first plist) (fourth plist))
                       (* (second plist) (third plist)))
                    2)
                 (.signed-area (cddr plist))))))
  (abs (.signed-area plist))) ;; final absolute
```

Instead of dividing by to for every summand, you can do it also at the
very end on the entire absolute sum. So, very very minimally more efficient - but in the praxis totally negligible improvement.

```
(define (signed-area plist)
  (define (.signed-area plist)
    (cond ((< (length plist) 3) 0)
          (else (+
                 (- (* (first plist) (fourth plist))
                    (* (second plist) (third plist)))
                 (.signed-area (cddr plist))))))
  (* (/ 1 2) (abs (.signed-area plist))))
```

**Solution II - tail-call recursion**

This is a technique which is memory saving and avoids nesting of recursive calls for the interpreter. So generally regarded as best practice.
In addition, you can more clearly see what happens between the steps - because
you have just to concentrate on `acc` and what is done on it at each recursion step - then you understand the formula/procedure undertaken on the results of each single step. Because of these two reasons, tail-call recursion is the preferred method for lisp-programmers to formulate recursive functions.

```
(define (signed-area plist)
  (define (.signed-area plist acc)         ; introduce accumulator 
    (cond ((< (length plist) 3) (* (/ 1 2) (abs acc)))
          (else (.signed-area (cddr plist) ; in next round remove first pair
                              (+ (- (* (first plist) (fourth plist))
                                    (* (second plist) (third plist)))
                                 acc)))))  ; add shoelace product to accumulator
  (.signed-area plist 0)) ; call inner recursive function with accumulator start value 0
;
```

**Test**

All three function definitions give the correct result `2`:

```
(signed-area (list 1 2 3 4 5 6))
;; => 2
```

For checking/testing, calculate by hand the example:

```
;; to check, calculate shoelace by hand:
;; visualize:
;; 1 2
;; 3 4
;; 5 6
;
;; and then calculate:
(* (/ 1 2)
   (abs (+ (- (* 1 4)
              (* 2 3))
           (- (* 3 6)
              (* 4 5)))))
;; => 2
```

**For list-of-posn**

```
(define (signed-area list-of-posn)
  (define (.signed-area list-of-posn acc)         ; introduce accumulator 
    (cond ((< (length list-of-posn) 2) (* (/ 1 2) (abs acc)))
          (else (.signed-area (cdr list-of-posn) ; in next round remove first posn
                              (+ (- (* (posn-x (first list-of-posn)) (posn-y (second list-of-posn)))
                                    (* (posn-x (second list-of-posn)) (posn-y (first list-of-posn))))
                                 acc)))))  ; add shoelace product to accumulator
  (.signed-area list-of-posn 0)) ; call inner recursive function with accumulator start value 0
```

Comment: why there is a definition inside the definition?

Comment: sorry, but how would that work if is a list of posn?

Comment: @Femando That is a typical technique in Racket. You create in this way local functions. And this is very typical if you define tail-call recursive functions.

Comment: @Femando - for list-of-posns see my added last section of the answer!